# D programming & iPhone

Tags: iphone, macos, d

I've just started learning "D Programming".  I'd like to deploy my programs on an iPhone. which has me wondering; is is possible to develop for a Mac or iPhone using D?.  I'd like the application to be completely written D or at least minimal objective-c.  Am I starting a hopeless battle by choosing D over the other mainstream languages (c/c++/java/objective-c/c#)?

Comment: I have a nail. I want to knock the nail into this wood. I know how to use a banana, but whenever I hit the nail with the banana, the banana goes mushy and doesn't work. I have heard of a hammer, but I don't know how to use one or want to learn to use one. How can I knock a nail into some wood with a banana?

Comment: @Jasarien: freeze the banana, then try knocking the nail into the wood with it. (Old comment, but since caspin's edit bumped it I just *had* to reply.)

Comment: Actually just have Steve Jobs sign the banana and it will work perfectly, just ask any mac head.  Honestly though, Obj-C is at least as weird as D.  The difference is the objective-c banana has special gold plated nails that it drives very effectively.  However the these Steve Jobs bananas cannot be used to drive nails in general or they go mushy.  I suspect @Jasarien is a little sensitive to people not wanting to use Obj-C.  That and he posses the whit to make good banana jokes.

Comment: Not so much that I'm sensitive people not using Obj-C on the iPhone, but more that I don't understand why people go out of their way to try to make things harder for themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to do **D Programming Language** on the iPhone.

On Mac OS though, you can use GCC to compile your **D** code.

Comment: Oh my goodness, I don't understand why new compiler designers are not taking it seriously to make developers life easier. I read somewhere, D is designed by experiences of practical problems usually developer face. Anyway, Thanks to taking time to explain it to me.

Comment: It's theoretically possible, but someone has to do the job of creating and maintaining bindings to iPhone and OS X libraries, as well as a compiler capable of generating code for the said architecture (there's the GDC compiler based on GCC, but it has no active maintainer at the moment).

Comment: Compiler engineers, like the rest of us, have only finite resources of time and money.  They aren't going to drop everything and add a new language simply because it's new.  Besides, when it comes to making developers' lives easier, I'd much rather have more capable, easy-to-access frameworks than a "better" language.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/435990/why-do-programmers-love-hate-objective-c

Comment: D is just one of the latest in a long line of nifty new languages which are supposed to make our lives easier. There are hundreds of languages only a handful of which are used by more than 1% of all programmers. Every year dozens of new languages are put forward but only a handful every decade ever turn out to be successful. If you're just starting out, you should learn the tried and true and leave the experimental languages to people who've seen a lot of languages come and go over the years.

Comment: @TechZen, I agree with you and hope we're both wrong.  D 2.0 brings some serious firepower the language wars, addressing complicated issues like: easier concurrency, java/c# and C++ style resource management, c++ strength templates manageable syntax, etc.  My one hope is that with big name backers like Andrei Alexandrescu, and Walter Bright D will have better than average chance at success.

Comment: I don't think its a matter of "backing" but of real world, immediate utility. The most widely used languages are not those that are well designed to handle specific problems but those that are relatively minimalistic, highly adaptable and capable of easy evolution. C and Perl are good examples of very ugly and easy to screw up languages that nevertheless dominate their domains because of their ability to evolve into almost any niche. Successful languages usually start out as ad hoc tools that evolve overtime into market share monsters.

Answer (score 4):

Never say never, michelf has been working on a D/Objective-C bridge for a while.

Here's the old site: http://michelf.com/projects/d-objc-bridge/

The current efforts can be watched at https://github.com/michelf/dmd/tree/d-objc
Have a look at the readme.

Answer (score 1):

take a peek at http://michelf.com/projects/d-for-xcode/
it's the installer package for D for Xcode (the latest version, so not the uncompleted D 1.0 version from 2007). 
although since xcode 4.2 is just released, this installer is a bit out of date and not fully supported yet. but for me it works just fine, except from the fancy syntax highlighting and auto-completion.
be sure to give it a look :)